# Why wont my Insert function for a list make new nodes?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Hello My problem with this code is on my 2nd else loop; i never enter it and therefore i never make new nodes for my list. can anyone help me see what i am missing?

```
    bool List::Insert(int data)
{
    Node* P = new Node;
    if(P==NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        P ->info = data;
        P ->next = NULL;
            if(Head == NULL)
            {
                Head = P;
            }
            else
            {
                Node* lastNode;
                for(lastNode = Head; lastNode ->next != NULL; lastNode = lastNode ->next)
                {
                    lastNode ->next = P;
                }
            }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: else is not a loop.   I only see one loop in here.  What do you mean by "my 2nd else loop"?

Comment: @abelenky, the "2nd else loop" would be the "loop inside the 2nd else" :-) In other words, as you state, the only loop. You could read it as the "2nd (else loop)" (wrong since there's only one and there's no such beast) or the "(2nd else) loop" (right in this case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
Node* lastNode;
for(lastNode = Head; lastNode ->next != NULL; lastNode = lastNode ->next)
{
    lastNode ->next = P;
}
```

is dead wrong. It will change the `next` pointer, for *every single node* currently in the list, to point to your new node. You need to only change the pointer in the *last* node:

```
Node* lastNode = Head;
while (lastNode->next != NULL)
    lastNode = lastNode->next;
lastNode->next = P;
```

You may also, for efficiency, want to maintain a separate `Tail` pointer (in addition to your `Head`) so that you can simply replace that whole operation with:

```
Tail->next = P;
Tail = P;
```

That way, you won't have to traverse the entire list every time you want to append a new node. Your code then becomes something like (without the traversal, and with updating the tail pointer as well):

```
// Prepare new node.

Node *P = new Node;
P->info = data;
P->next = NULL;

// If list empty, set head and tail to new node, otherwise
//   append it.

if (Head == NULL) {
    Head = P;
    Tail = P;
} else {
    Tail->next = P;
    Tail = P;
}
```

I'll stop short of criticising the fact that your `Insert` method *doesn't* actually insert but rather appends. My near-anal-retentive nitpicking nature is unlikely to  endear me to you:-)

Comment: great! but how should i initialize lastNode b/c i get a runtime error b/c its not initialized.

Comment: Opps, sorry @Jake, didn't carry that over from the `for` loop. I've modified the code to properly initialise `lastNode`.

Answer (score 1):

lastNode ->next = P; // this must go after the for

Comment: leave the for body empty and after the for body place this line